# Is there a way to use same set of <div> elements to be called in multiple pages in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I am designing a web page and I need to have a `<div>` which will  have 10 dropdown boxes. But the requirement got extended and now same `<div>` needs to be replicated in 6 different pages again. I don't want to replicate the same piece of code in all 6 jsp pages.is there a way which can let me write the code once and call it multiple times in jsp pages?

Currently I am writing the same code in all the pages again.

Below is the code snippet.

```
<div>
<label> Programming languages </label>
<select>
<option> select </option>
<option> Java </option>
<option> Python </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can put that piece of code in separate page and can use [include](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html) to get that code in all your jsp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options:

Create a JSP page having this content and dynamically include it from other JSP pages (included every time dynamically).

```
<jsp:include page="common.jsp" />
```

In case the included content is static do static include (included once statically):

```
<%@ include file="date.jsp"%>
```

Create a tag for such a common thing using JSTL like below:

```
<mytaglib:mycomponent value="a" />
```

Get more information here:

- [JSP reusing pages](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html)
- [JSP tag library](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/java.920/a96657/taglibs.htm)